# Cannot read /proc/<pid>/smaps, despite having mode 444 permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

I'm trying to write a script that examines memory usage for running processes.
To do this, it needs to read /proc/*/smaps files.

Processes owned by root have the permission set to '-r--r--r--', which *should* be readable by everyone, right?

example output of ls -l [EDIT: now with directory permissions]

```
ls -l /proc/939/smaps
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 2012-07-11 12:11 /proc/939/smaps

ls -ld /proc/939/smaps
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 2012-07-11 12:11 /proc/939/smaps
```

attempt to read:

```
cat /proc/939/smaps
cat: /proc/939/smaps: Permission denied
```

is there something obvious I'm missing here?

EDIT2:
On further investigation, other files, such as /proc//cmdline, are readable, so it might just be a special case for the smaps file?

Comment: check the permissions of the parent directory

Comment: sorry I didn't include those before. the directory is also readable, and I can ls in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, reading `/proc/PID/smaps` requires the `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` capability.

You can add this capability to your application using `sudo setcap cap_sys_ptrace+ep YOUR_APPLICATION`.